# Getting multiple elements' text with Jquery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I am trying to get the value of a table cell.

For example

```
<table id='projects'>
        
        <tr>
        <td id='a'>aaaaa</td>
        <td id='b'>bbbbb</td>
        <td id='c'>ccccc</td>
        <td id='d'>eeeee</td>
        <td id='e'>ddddd</td>
        </tr>
</table>
<a id='test' href='#'>test </a>
```

I want to get aaaaa,bbbbb,ccccc,eeeee,ddddd and assign them to my array

I believe I can get the value with my Jquery code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
    var tableVal=new Array();
    tableVal['a']=$('#a').text();
    tableVal['b']=$('#b').text();
    tableVal['c']=$('#c').text();
    tableVal['d']=$('#d').text();
    tableVal['e']=$('#e').text();   
    
    })
 });
```

However, I think it's not very maintainable and take lots of code if I have 20  tags. I was wondering if I can do it with `.each` or any better way to archive this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do something like below,

```
var tableVal= [];

$('#projects tr:eq(0) td').each (function () {
   tableVal[this.id] = $(this).text();
});
```

Note: [:eq(0)](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) - means 1st row.. Modify accordingly if you want to do for all rows or let me know if you need help with that.

Comment: yes I do need an associative array and your answer is perfect for me.  I don't understand the purposed of '(index)' in your code though. Would you explain? Thanks.

Comment: You don't need the function (index) there.

Comment: map is more succinct

Answer (score 37):

If you actually want an Array, use `.map()` with `.toArray()`.

```
var tableVal = $('#projects td').map(function(i,v) {
    return $(this).text();
}).toArray();
```

Otherwise if you're actually going to use non numeric indices, you want an Object, using the techniques in the other answers.

Comment: +1 - nice answer :).. However OP want's something like tableVal['a'].. isn't map returns you an it? correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: OP wants an associative array.. In you case, I think tableVal['a'] will be undefined.

Comment: @SKS: Yes, your answer would be the way to do that. +1 up there. :)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can :).

```
var tableVals= {}
$('#projects td').each(function() {
    tableVals[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).text();
});
```

Please, remember to use object instead of array if your keys are not numeric.

Comment: Thanks, SKS is faster so I gave my answer to him. +1.

Answer (score 6):

First, give your `tr` an `id`:

```
<tr id="rowToGetDataFrom">
```

Then you can get the array you want like this:

```
var tableVal = $('#rowToGetDataFrom td').map(function () { return $(this).text(); });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alecgorge/3ApnB/

Comment: tableVal['a'] = undefined. OP want's tableVal['a'] = 'aaaaa'. Map translates all items in an array or object to new array of items. OP wants an associative array.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
var tableVal = [];
$('#test').click(
    function(){
        $('#projects td').each(
             function(){
                  tableVal.push($(this).text());
             });
    });
```