# How to get all textbox value which have dynamic ID

Tags: php, jquery, dynamic

i have created form which have text box in foreach loop for multiple textbox, textbox have dynamic Id.
so id for textbox creating like `id="cmbeditqty-1"`.
but if two textbox will create then how can i get those two values in different variable?

```
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" class="cmbeditqty" id="cmbeditqty-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 250px;"  name="qty"> 
</td>  
<td>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cmbeditprice-<?php echo $i; ?>" style="width: 250px;"  name="itemprice"> 
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

From JavaScript's perspective they're not "dynamic", they've `id` values like any other.  You would just need to select them based on some common way to identify them.  In this case they all [start with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) the same string, so you can use that in a selector:

```
$('input[id^="cmbeditqty-"]')
```

Like any other jQuery selector, this will return a list of matching elements.  You can pull the values from elements in that list like any other.

Comment: getting TypeError: $ is not a function
 

var check = $('input[id^=cmbeditqty-]');

Comment: @RahulPatil: Sounds like you forgot to include jQuery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2194992/jquery-is-not-defined

Comment: no sir i got an alert(123); which i put for testing

Comment: @RahulPatil: Your last comment doesn't make sense.  Please elaborate.

Comment: $(document).ready(function ($) {
        
var mainqty = $("#cmbqty").val();

    $('.updateSingleSku').click(function($){
        alert(123);

      var check = $('input[id^=cmbeditqty-]').val();
      alert(check);
    });
    });

Comment: @RahulPatil: Your event handlers are overriding the `$` variable.  `$` is the default jQuery function.  You are overwriting it with something that *isn't* a function.  Hence the error.  Don't overwrite the `$` variable in your event handlers.

Comment: Remove the `$` from `function($)`

Comment: yes, but its showing only first textbox value.. how can i get bot text box value

Comment: @RahulPatil: The code in your comment is only attempting to display one value.  If you want all of the values then you need to *loop* over the results.  For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9057388/getting-multiple-elements-value-with-jquery

Comment: by using each() function. i got both values in one variable. i want those values for comapire third variable which is outside o each loop.

Comment: @RahulPatil: This sounds like a separate problem.  Originally you'd asked how to select multiple elements which start with the same `id` string, which has been answered.  If you've structured your code in such a way that some other problems also exist, I suggest you open a Stack Overflow question in which you demonstrate that problem and ask about it.